# Parsing "the main sources of contention being over the rights"

Tags: meaning, prepositional-phrases, participle-clauses, parsing

> *There were periodic challenges to the absolute authority of the king: **the main sources of contention being over the rights** of religious
>   minorities (Jansenists and Protestants); and the rights of the
>   parlements.*
>
> Source: Marisa Linton: Choosing Terror, p. 27.

I approximately understand the meaning of the sentence: the two main sources which opposed the official ideology of the absolute authority of the king in France in the 18th century stemmed from religious minorities and parlements. But what's meant by "being over the rights" in the clause?

Comment: +! This is a good question. It deserves more up-votes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence is carelessly constructed, so it won't sustain a strict parse; but here's what's going on.

*Over* here is attached to *contention*.  Verbs like *contend, quarrel, dispute, argue* often take a preposition phrase with *over* as a complement  designating the matter which is disputed:

> The sisters quarreled **over** who should get their mother's silver.
>   The king and his opponents contended **over** the rights of minorities and parlements.

A noun derived from a verb often may take as a post-positioned modifier the same sort of preposition phrase which acts as the verb's complement.

> [<sub>CLAUSE</sub>They contended **over** X.] → [<sub>NOUN PHRASE</sub>Their contention **over** X]

From there the attributive PP is easily recast as a predicative PP.

> [<sub>NOUN PHRASE</sub>Their contention over X] → [<sub>CLAUSE</sub>Their contention **was** over X.]

And that finite clause may be recast as a non-finite clause so it can be subordinated:

> [<sub>FINITE CLAUSE</sub>Their contention **was** over X.] → [<sub>NON-FINITE CLAUSE</sub>... their contention **being** over X.]

A participle clause like this may be employed as an *absolute construction*:

> ... a grammatical construction standing apart from a normal or usual syntactical relation with other words or sentence elements. It can be a non-finite clause that is subordinate in form and modifies an entire sentence ... —[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction).

The participle clause headed by *being* modifies the main clause, supplying the matters ***over*** which the king's authority was challenged.

What throws a monkey wrench into this particular absolute construction is Dr. Linton's expansion of *contention* to *sources of contention*.

> The main sources of contention being over X ...

Now the subject of *being* is no longer *contention* but *sources*; and it is not idiomatic to speak of a source as ***over*** X. The *sources* of contention, in the sense in which Dr. Linton uses *source*, is *X* itself. Dr. Linton should have written:

> ... the main sources of contention being <s>over</s> the rights of religious minorities (Jansenists and Protestants) and the rights of the parlements.

I hasten to add that this is a very minor error, which would pass entirely unnoticed in speech. Dr. Linton is a graceful writer; I imagine she rewrote this sentence many times, and somehow the *over* never got deleted. It's very easy to make this sort of error, and very hard to spot it.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. But I am a little bit stuck in terms of the meaning. I am not able to decide whether the religious minorities and parlements theoretically and practically called into question the idea of the absolute monarchy. Or the king himself as an absolute ruler dictated and determined how to deal with the rights of minorities and parlements

Comment: @bart-leby They were stuck, too: that's what they were contending over.

Comment: I could feel the *heat* of their contention being *over* the rights of religious minorities. :) However, *being* is redundant now.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment

> ... the main sources of contention being ...

is the phrase leading to the enumeration of the *sources*.  The enumeration contains two sources.  One source is *over the rights of .. minorities .." and the other "the rights of the parlements" (sp? the word is "parliaments")

The use of present participle "*being*" can be seen in many similar constructs.  For example

> An upper house, often called a Senate (or by other terms), is one of two chambers of a bicameral legislature, the other chamber **being** the lower house. (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_house)).